# Cannot get parse relation

Tags: parse-platform

I have two objects, User and Category with a many-many relationship.  Users have a relation column with Categories.  There is a user that has a relationship with the `Art` category.  I am trying to retrieve all users with a relationship with the `Art` category:

```
var filterByCategory = function(category){
    var RelatedUser = Parse.Object.extend("User");
    var query = new Parse.Query(RelatedUser);
    query.equalTo("categories", category);
    query.ascending("username");
    query.find({
        success: function (results) {
            $scope.relatedUsers = results;
            $scope.$apply();
        },
        failure: function (results) {
            $scope.relatedUsers = [];
            $scope.apply();
        }
    });
}
```

`category` is retrieved from here:

```
<ul class="category-list">
    <li class="category" 
        data-ng-click="filterByCategory(category)" 
        data-ng-repeat="category in categories">

        {{category.attributes.categoryName}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

There are no results coming back from this request.  All users come back if I remove this line:

> query.equalTo("categories", category);

The object being sent is definitely a category from my Parse app (I have tested it by specifically pulling the `Art` category from the "database").

Comment: Try adding `console.log(category.id);` to confirm that the category is a valid pointer, then check one of the users to see if they have a category with that ID in the data browser. This will eliminate if it is a data issue.

Answer (score 0):

Relations should be queried by 'relation' method

```
var relation = user.relation("categories");
relation.query().equalTo('', '').find(...)
```

But it implies you have to have user object already fetched. I am not sure if you can just query 'by relation' :| for all users connected with specific category.